# Angular ng-select not selecting the value while creating the dynamic control

Tags: angular, typescript, html-select, angular-ngselect

I have a requirement to add city dynamically using ng-select because i need search option while entering city name. Lets say i have two city name saved in the new form and whil doing edit i have to load the two cities in two different ng-select For ex: ng-select should select on page load for the first control(ng-select)newyork and second control(texas) and goon.

```html
<div *ngFor="let savedEntry of savedEntries; let i = index;">
  <ng-select [(ngModel)]="savedEntry.name" [id]="'city-id' + i" name="city">
    <ng-option value="">Select</ng-option>
    <ng-option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city">
      {{ city}}
    </ng-option>
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

sample data

```
  public savedEntries: any[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'chicago' },
    { id: 2, name: 'NewYork' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Texas' }
  ];

  public cities: string[] = ['SanDiego', 'NewYork', 'Texas', 'Ohio', 'chicago', 'Houston', 'Phoenix'];
```

Here im trying to preselect the default city but it throws an error that ng-option doesnt support  option. Any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: I don't get it why you need `[selected]` attribute in `<ng-option>`, as `[(ngModel)]` will do the job for the value binding & selection. And while ng-select doesn't have API for `selected` directive/Input. Thus, you should remove the `[selected]="city === capitalCity.name"` .

Comment: Another concern is you are trying to loop the `capitalCities` and refer to the same `selectedCity` for the ngModel.  Thus, I doubt the result for `selectedCity` will be correct. Will be great if you can share the sample data & expected output.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to preselect the default value for your `ng-select` elements based on the `capitalCity` values. However, the `[selected]` attribute is not supported in `ng-option` elements. Instead, you can achieve this using the `[compareWith]` attribute provided by `ng-select`.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve the desired behavior:

```html
<div *ngFor="let capitalCity of capitalCities; let i = index;">
  <ng-select [(ngModel)]="capitalCity.name" [id]="'city-id' + i" name="city" [clearable]="false" [compareWith]="compareCities">
    <ng-option value="">Select</ng-option>
    <ng-option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city.name">
      {{ city.name }}
    </ng-option>
  </ng-select>
</div>
```

In your component class, define the `compareCities` function to customize how the comparison between the selected value and the option values is performed:

```js
compareCities(city1: any, city2: any): boolean {
  return city1 && city2 ? city1 === city2 : city1 === city2;
```

In this example, the `compareCities` function compares the selected city name (`capitalCity.name`) with the option values (`city.name`). If the comparison returns `true`, the corresponding option will be preselected.

Keep in mind that in the above example, `capitalCity.name` should exactly match one of the city names in the cities array. If the capital city name doesn't match any city name in the list, the `Select` option will be displayed.

Also, make sure that you have the necessary properties and structures defined in your component class (`capitalCities`, `cities`, etc.) for this code to work correctly.

Comment: thanks for the reply..i want to preselect the default value for the dynamically generated ng-select..dont want to comapre..i have updated the question to avoid confusions

Comment: Thanks for updating the question! Unfortunately I'm not sure either how to do that...